# Default pip installation of Dask gives "ImportError: No module named toolz"

Tags: python, installation, pip, importerror, dask

I installed [Dask](https://github.com/dask/dask) using pip like this:

```
pip install dask
```

and when I try to do `import dask.dataframe as dd` I get the following error message:

```
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .async import get_sync as get
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 120, in <module>
    from toolz import identity
ImportError: No module named toolz
No module named toolz
```

I noticed that [the documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/install.html#pip) states

> `pip install dask`: Install only dask, which depends only on the standard library. This is appropriate if you only want the task schedulers.

so I'm confused as to why this didn't work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In order to use Dask's parallelized dataframes (built on top of pandas), you have to tell pip to install some "extras" ([reference](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#installing-setuptools-extras)), as mentioned in the [Dask installation documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/install.html#pip):

```
pip install "dask[dataframe]"
```

Or you could just do

```
pip install "dask[complete]"
```

to get the whole bag of tricks. *NB: The double-quotes may or may not be required in your shell.*

The justification for this is (or was) mentioned in the Dask documentation:

> We do this so that users of the lightweight core dask scheduler aren’t required to download the more exotic dependencies of the collections (numpy, pandas, etc.)

As mentioned in [Obinna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54333641/785213), you may wish to do this inside a virtualenv, or use `pip install --user` to put the libraries in your home directory, if, say, you don't have admin privileges on to the host OS.

#### Extra details

At Dask 0.13.0 and below, there was a requirement on [toolz](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/)' `identity` function within `dask/async.py`. There is <strike>an open</strike> a closed pull request associated with GitHub [issue #1849](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1849) to remove this dependency. <strike>In the meantime</strike> If, for some reason, you are stuck with an older version of dask, you can work around *that* particular issue by simply doing `pip install toolz`.

But this wouldn't (completely) fix your problem with `import dask.dataframe as dd` anyway. Because you'd still get *this* error:

```
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

or if you had pandas installed already, you'd get `ImportError: No module named cloudpickle`. So, `pip install "dask[dataframe]"` seems to be the way to go if you're in this situation.

Comment: I think it should be pip install "dask[complete]". Without the double quotes, it could throw an error >> no matches found.

Comment: @ObinnaNnenanya It might depend on your shell (works for me, no double quotes). But double quotes won't hurt so I updated the answer anyway. `:)`

Comment: After running `python -m pip install "dask[complete]"` as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/install.html#pip) I still get the error.

Comment: @user171780 I recommend trying in a clean virtualenv (`python -m venv venv; source venv/bin/activate`, or as appropriate for your platform) before giving up entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and this was what fixed it for me.

1. Create a virtual env for your project
2. Cd your project directory (not required if you're good with directory navigation)
3. Activate you virtual env
4. `pip install "dask[complete]"` : This will install everything. You may wish to install only a given component like dataframe, then use `pip install "dask[dataframe]"`

The bottomline was that I had to be in my virtual environment; this would install dask for this env only.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using anaconda on windows machine, here are the steps that solved this issue:

1. conda install dask
2. conda install dask-core
3. Install this based on a
   github comment [!pip install tornado==5.0.0 distributed==2.15 dask-ml[complete]](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/962#issuecomment-383522581)
4. restart my anaconda.

Comment: Hi Hassan, thanks for your input. The question is tagged `pip`, though. Perhaps if a similar question for Anaconda does not exist yet, you could create your own version of this question (and [answer it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command.

```
pip install "dask[dataframe]"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

requeriments.txt working:

```
awscli==1.16.69
botocore=1.13.0
boto3==1.9.79
numpy==1.16.2
dask[complete]
```

Comment: If you have `dask[complete]` you neither need a separate specific numpy nor a specific pandas version for dask to work. Can you elaborate why one should use these specific versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ss below:

The error i got

[image: 1]

Dask version

[image: 2]

You can solve this situation like this:

1. Find daskpack from pypi https://pypi.org/project/dask/2022.5.0/
2. Check the required python version for the dask version selected from the requirements.
3. Find the dask package suitable for your python version from the release history page of the pypi dask page.
4. Go back to colab and remove dask completely
   !pip uninstall dask
5. Install the dask version you just found
   example : !pip install dask==2022.2.0
6. Your dask version should be the same as your distributed version. For this, find the distributed version corresponding to your dask version from pypi
7. Uninstall distributed from colab
   !pip uninstall distributed
8. Install the appropriate distributed version
   ex: !pip install distributed==2022.2.0
9. install auto-sklearn
   pip install auto-sklearn

note: auto-sklearn must be installed for each colab notebook and since colab will delete these changes after 12 hours, it must be installed from the beginning.

footnote: you can correct me for my mistakes and omissions. I hope the problem is solved for you as it was solved for me.