# Dask dataframe in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, docker, dask

I need to install a few python packages in a Docker container via `requirements.txt`, using `pip install`. One of the packages is `dask`. However, when installing it, it throws an error because it cannot find the package `toolz`. The question has been answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453473/default-pip-installation-of-dask-gives-importerror-no-module-named-toolz), i.e. by typing

```
pip install "dask[dataframe]"
```

However, I need to fix it by adding the line in the `requirements.txt`. Something like:

```
pandas==0.23.4
dask==1.0.0
???dask[dataframe]???
```

How should it look like in the requirements file? What should I write in place of the *???*

Comment: Have you tried `dask[dataframe]` alone, i.e., with the "?" characters replaced by nothing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dask[dataframe]==???` where `???` is the version you want to specify will work without problems.

E.g. `dask[dataframe]==1.1.1`.

Comment: Is the version of `dask[dataframe]` same as the one of `dask` ?

Comment: @giosans I believe so, the brackets just [denote a subset of the dependencies](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/install.html#pip).